# Is it possible to setup bash aliases that work in conemu as they do in cygwin?

Tags: windows-10, shell, cygwin, conemu, bash-alias

So I have conemu setup to use cygwin as my shell and have it using the specified home directory I setup in my .bashrc file in /home of my cygwin directory.

Here is what I have setup in the environments settings of conemu:

```
set PATH=%ConEmuBaseDir%\Scripts;%PATH%
set HOME=C:\cygwin64\home\
```

This is what I have setup in the tasks settings for CygWin bash task:

```
set HOME= & set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & %ConEmuDrive%\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive\cygwin64\bin"
```

Yes I have tried the aliases in cygwin itself and they work without any issues so this appears to be an issue specific to conemu. An example of the on of the aliases is:

```
alias shortname='ssh username@servername'
```

When I try to run shortname in conemu I get the error "command not found". Nothing overly complex and since it works in cygwin I am a bit perplexed. Thanks in advance for any help. Please note I am running the latest stable version of conemu 160724 (64 bit) and cygwin terminal is also 64 bit version.

Comment: "tried the aliases in cygwin itself" - cygwin is not an application. Have you tried to run bash.exe, which **is the shell**, from `Win+R`?

Answer (score 0):

ConEmu supports native Windows console aliases. Cygwin **does not**.
Setup cygwin aliases in cygwin profile. There is no other way, until cygwin maintainers implement native Windows console aliases support.

https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsEnvironment.html

Comment: Okay so I setup the aliases in the .bashrc in the cygwin directory (as mentioned previously) and noticed that the console that opens when I launch conemu, which is a cygwin bash console, none of the aliases work. However, if I open a new console everything including the bash aliases from cygwin work just fine. Is there a piece of configuration in settings I can change so I don't have to open a new console every time I open conemu?

Comment: Where are you putting the alias ? May be you are looking for a bash login shell to read all the bash config files.

Comment: C:\cygwin64\home\username and there is a .bashrc file which is where I am making these aliases.